# Could not able to initialize Twilio Programmable Chat Client in Android

Tags: java, android, chat, twilio

Getting Error : `TwilioApplication: Login error. Error 0:4 Client received positive response code, but response payload is not suitable, unable to set FPA token`

When I Tried initializing client in Web(Java script) it worked and I can able to see my channels.

Comment: Can you share the code you're using that isn't working?